# clCreateContext succeeds, but clCreateCommandQueue fails with -33

Tags: c++, c, opencl

I have an interesting problem on a machine with an integrated Intel card.

`clCreateContext()` returns a valid context using the device I want to create the context on.  The returned error is `CL_SUCCESS`.  However, passing the context to `clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties()` results in an error code -33, or `CL_INVALID_DEVICE`.  I did a double take and made sure that I'm checking the error correctly.  Why would I be able to create a context on a device, but not a command queue?

Comment: Can you post all the code as a MCVE? It may simply be you are not passing the proper context device to `clCreateCommandQueue()`

Answer (score 1):

Try doing a `clCreateCommandQueue()` (OpenCL 1.0) instead of `clCreateCommandQueueWithProperties()` (OpenCL 2.0).

The latter fails here with both Intel (proprietary) and NVIDIA runtimes. Don't know why, though.